# Consolidating SQL Results into Single Cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table of data in SQL Server 2008 with App Names and Department where that data is installed.

I'd like to go from returning a record for each Department where the App is installed to all the departments concatenated or combined in a single cell for each Application.

Is this possible?  Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: [this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) might help you.

Comment: Oh looks like there's an [open source CLR extension](http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/documentation) that might do this too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE([App Name] VARCHAR(20),[Department Install] VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('Office','Finance'),('Office','Accounting'),('Acrobat','Finance'),
('Acrobat','Accounting'),('Acrobat','HR')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT t.[App Name]
      ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + [Department Install] [text()]
              FROM @TABLE
              WHERE [App Name] = t.[App Name]
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
              ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1 ,2,' ') AS [Department Install]
FROM @TABLE t
GROUP BY t.[App Name]
```

**Result Set**

```
╔══════════╦══════════════════════════╗
║ App Name ║    Department Install    ║
╠══════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║ Acrobat  ║  Finance, Accounting, HR ║
║ Office   ║  Finance, Accounting     ║
╚══════════╩══════════════════════════╝
```